# Reduce/fold over scala sequence with grouping

Tags: scala

In scala, given an Iterable of pairs, say `Iterable[(String, Int])`,
is there a way to accumulate or fold over the `._2`s based on the `._1`s? Like in the following, add up all the #s that come after *A* and separately the # after *B*

```
List(("A", 2), ("B", 1), ("A", 3))
```

I could do this in 2 steps with groupBy

```
val mapBy1 = list.groupBy( _._1 )
for ((key,sublist) <- mapBy1) yield (key, sublist.foldLeft(0) (_+_._2))
```

but then I would be allocating the sublists, which I would rather avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the `Map` as you go and convert it back to a `List` after the fact.

```
listOfPairs.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)){
      case (m,(k,v)) => m + (k -> (v + m(k)))
    }.toList
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
list.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) {
   case (map, (k,v)) => map + (k -> (map.getOrElse(k, 0) + v))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `groupBy` with `mapValues`:

```
list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).toList
res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((A,5), (B,1))
```